# Como puedo agregar otro array a este codigo

Tags: php, select

quiero agregar un style color según corresponda a cada selección ejemplo red me debería quedar así como muestro 
 pero no se como agregar otro array para utilizarlo en el mismo foreach que supongo que asi se debe realizar alguien me podría dar algún ejemplo por favor la verdad es la primera vez que escribo aqui no se si lo hice bien o no pero intento aprender mas

`<option value="red" style="color:#FF0000">Color Red</option>`

```
<div class="control-group">
                                        <?php
                                            $opciones = array(
                                            'red' => 'Color Red',
                                            'pink' => 'Color Pink',
                                            'purple' => 'Color Purple',
                                            'deeppurple' => 'Color DeepPurple',
                                            'indigo' => 'Color Indigo',
                                            'blue' => 'Color Blue',
                                            'lightblue' => 'Color LightBlue',
                                            'cyan' => 'Color Cyan',
                                            'teal' => 'Color Teal',
                                            'green' => 'Color Green',
                                            'lightgreen' => 'Color LightGreen',
                                            'lime' => 'Color Lime',
                                            'yellow' => 'Color Yellow',
                                            'amber' => 'Color Amber',
                                            'orange' => 'Color Orange',
                                            'deeporange' => 'Color DeepOrange',
                                            'brown' => 'Color Brown',
                                            'grey' => 'Color Grey',
                                            'bluegrey' => 'Color BlueGrey',
                                            'darkblue' => 'Color DarkBlue',
                                            'black' =>'Color Black'
                                            );
                                            $seleccionado = $row['abtn'];
                                        ?>
                                        <label class="control-label" for="basicinput">Color Botones</label>
                                        <div class="controls">
    <select name="abtn" id="form1" class="input-group col-xs-12" >

                                            <?php foreach($opciones as $key => $opcion ){
                                                if($key == $seleccionado){
                                                    echo ' <option value="'.$key.'"  selected>'.$opcion.'</option>';
                                                }else{
                                                    echo ' <option value="'.$key.'" >'.$opcion.'</option>';
                                                }
                                            }?>

      </select>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

<select name="abtn" id="form1" class="input-group col-xs-12">

                                             <option value="red" style="color:#FF0000">Color Red</option> <option value="pink" style="color:#FFC0CB">Color Pink</option> <option value="purple" style="color:#800080">Color Purple</option> <option value="deeppurple" style="color:#673AB7">Color DeepPurple</option> <option value="indigo" style="color:#3F51B5">Color Indigo</option> <option value="blue" style="color:#2196F3">Color Blue</option> <option value="lightblue" style="color:#03A9F4">Color LightBlue</option> <option value="cyan" style="color:#00BCD4">Color Cyan</option> <option value="teal" style="color:#009688">Color Teal</option> <option value="green" style="color:#4CAF50">Color Green</option> <option value="lightgreen" style="color:#8BC34A">Color LightGreen</option> <option value="lime" style="color:#CDDC39">Color Lime</option> <option value="yellow" selected="">Color Yellow</option> <option value="amber">Color Amber</option> <option value="orange" style="color:#FFC0CB">Color Orange</option> <option value="deeporange" style="color:#FFC0CB">Color DeepOrange</option> <option value="brown" style="color:#FFC0CB">Color Brown</option> <option value="grey" style="color:#FFC0CB">Color Grey</option> <option value="bluegrey" style="color:#FFC0CB">Color BlueGrey</option> <option value="darkblue" style="color:#FFC0CB">Color DarkBlue</option> <option value="black" style="color:#FFC0CB">Color Black</option>           
      </select>
```

Comment: La pregunta no se entiende: ¿quieres llenar elementos ´option` a partir del array o por el contrario quieres, partiendo de un `option` seleccionado sacar información del array? Explica también qué resultado final esperas. Tampoco se entiende a qué te refieres con *agregar otro array a este código* ¿qué otro array, con qué contenidos y para qué uso?

Comment: lo que sucede es que en el array que ya tengo quedaria asi mira hablando en html

Comment: lo agregue abajo porque aqui no podia t la idea es algo asi como este <option value="red" style="color:#FF0000">Color Red</option>

Comment: <option value="pink" style="color:#FFC0CB">Color Pink</option>

Comment: espero me logran entender

Comment: La pregunta no se entiende todavía. ¿Quieres agregar las claves de color a cada  miembro del array? ¿quieres crear un `option` con colores? ¿quieres usar el código de color para algo en otra parte?

Comment: Quiero agregar las claves de color a cada miembro del array